# selenium iterate through options in dropdown select

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium in python, and I have a dropdown that I'm trying to select from. Essentially, I just want to iterate through all the options, like so:

```
select first option 
  submit page 
  \\ do stuff
select second option 
  submit page 
  \\ do stuff
select third option 
  submit page 
  \\ do stuff
etc...
```

I know it's possible to do this if you know what each of the option values are (you just create a list of those values), but is there a way of just iterating through all the options when you don't know what the option values are?

Thanks!

Comment: Does Python have something like select_by_id? Which is a number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get list of all the options using `select.options`. Than you can select options using index.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("dropDown"))
options = select.options
for index in range(0, len(options) - 1):
    select.select_by_index(index)
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply iterate through all options:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("someId"))

for opt in select.options:
    # for example
    print(opt.text)
    opt.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the answer, question, shouldn't it be

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("dropDown"))
options = select.options
for index in range(0, len(options)):
    select.select_by_index(index)
    # do stuff
```

Comment: The only difference between this and the other answer is the ` - 1` on line 3.  Please explain the difference and why it is important.