# Using Python requests module to collect data tables from drop-down list from a webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, module, python-requests

I am trying to scrape information from this webpage-
https://www.dmr.nd.gov/oilgas/bakkenwells.asp

I want to collect all data tables from dropdown menu and use Beautiful Soup and requests module to pull the information.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.dmr.nd.gov/oilgas/bakkenwells.asp')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't easily do it with Beautifoul Soup only.

Since this website is a SPA (single page application), you need to perform clicks in order to get all the needed informations, you can't just requests the page, and BS4 does not offer that.

To do it, you can use Selenium module.
Here is an interesting answer on how to use Selenium to perform clicks on dropdown values that you can try.
[selenium iterate through options in dropdown select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559573/selenium-iterate-through-options-in-dropdown-select)

Have a nice day

Comment: Hey, is it possible to collect data table separately for each formation using just beautiful soup

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062946/how-to-scrape-through-single-page-application-websites-in-python-using-bs4